# How can i query wordnet database(mysql) to get all Synonyms and similar of a word?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have used this code to get definitions:

```
//assuming you've connected to your MySQL db
$word=$_GET['s']; //This variable stores the value given through url
if (ctype_alpha($word)){ // If it's alphabetical
  $word_clean=mysql_real_escape_string($word); //Sanitize it for MySQL
}else{
  //Not a valid word, error handle
  exit();
}
$query='SELECT wordno FROM word WHERE lemma=`$word_clean` LIMIT 1';
$result=mysql_query($query);


$query='SELECT synsetno FROM sense WHERE wordno=`$wordno`';


$query='SELECT definition FROM synset WHERE synsetno=`$synset`';
```

BUT NOW I want to get synonyms and similar of that word ($word);

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT  a.lemma, c.definition
FROM    word a
        INNER JOIN sense b
            ON a.wordno = b.wordNo
        INNER JOIN synset c
            ON b.synsetno = c. synsetno
WHERE   a.lemma = 'valueHere'
```

To fully gain knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: This returns definitions of particular synsets. Not the synonyms.

Answer (score 3):

A fast way to get a synonym/similar word using wordnet v3.0 with SQL:

```
SELECT w.lemma
FROM words AS w 
LEFT JOIN senses AS s ON s.wordid = w.wordid
LEFT JOIN senses AS s2 ON s2.synsetid = s.synsetid
LEFT JOIN words AS w2 ON w2.wordid = s2.wordid
WHERE w.lemma <> 'coder' 
AND w2.lemma = 'coder'
GROUP BY w.lemma
ORDER BY s.synsetid
```